# wordpress : how to display pages as featured images thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress

1.i have created some pages using the dashboard

2 add categories to those pages using the plugin

```
     http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-tags-and-category-to-page/
```

3 use those categories as a menu in apperance/menu

i now would like that when clicking on a certain category, the list of associated pages are shown not with their titles and contents but their featured images

this is how i would like it :

```
    http://wpshower.com/demo/?theme=portfolium
```

( this theme use portfolio objects and portfolio categories rather than normal posts ...and i dont know how to create a box to associate my pages to a portfolio category, i can only to posts categories )

Comment: What does the plugin documentation says about "querying" this page taxonomies?

Comment: @brasofilo nothing i am afraid